# Using for loop to scrape webpages in R

Tags: r, for-loop, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape multiple webpages by using the list of URLs (a csv file)

This is my dataset: https://www.mediafire.com/file/9qh516tdcto7is7/nyp_data.csv/file

The `url` column includes all the links that I am trying to use and scrape.

I tried to use `for()` loop by:

```
news_urls <- read_csv("nyp_data.csv")

library(rvest)
content_list <- vector()
for (i in 1:nrow(news_urls)) {
  nyp_url <- news_urls[i, 'url']
  nyp_html <- read_html(nyp_url)
  nyp_nodes <- nyp_html %>% 
    html_elements(".single__content")
  tag_name = ".single__content"
  nyp_texts <- nyp_html %>% 
    html_elements(tag_name) %>% 
    html_text()
{    content_list[i] <- nyp_texts[1]
  }}
```

However, I am getting an error that says:

> Error in UseMethod("read_xml") :    no applicable method for
> 'read_xml' applied to an object of class "c('tbl_df', 'tbl',
> 'data.frame')"

I believe the links that I have work well; they aren't broken and I can access to them by clicking an individual link.

If for loop isn't the one that I should be using here, do have any other idea to scarpe the content?

I also tried:

```
urls <- news_urls[,5] #identify the column with the urls
url_xml <- try(apply(urls, 1, read_html)) #apply the function read_html() to the `url` vector

textScraper <- function(x) {
  html_text(html_nodes (x, ".single__content")) %>% #in this data, my text is in a node called ".single__content"
    str_replace_all("\n", "") %>%
    str_replace_all("\t", "") %>%
    paste(collapse = '')
}

article_text <- lapply(url_xml, textScraper)
article_text[1]
```

but it kept me giving an error,

> Error in open.connection(x, "rb") : HTTP error 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error occures in this line:

```
nyp_html <- read_html(nyp_url)
```

As the error message tells you that the argument to `read_xml` (which is what is called internally by `read_html`) is a `data.frame` (amongst others, as it actually is a tibble).

This is because in this line:

```
nyp_url <- news_urls[i, 'url']
```

you are using single brackets to subset your data. Single brackets do return a data.frame containing the filtered data. You can avoid this by using double brackets like this:

```
nyp_url <- news_urls[[i, 'url']]
```

or this (which I usually find more readable):

```
nyp_url <- news_urls[i, ]$url
```

Either should fix your problem.
If you want to read more about using these notations you could look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1169456/the-difference-between-bracket-and-double-bracket-for-accessing-the-el).